# Problem with C code, I'm serching for maximum and minimum

Tags: c

I'm doing a Code to search the maximum, minimum and show the sum of an array. I have no problems with the sum and to show the array, but when I try to find the max and min is always a problem and the program always give me the number 9 and not the right numbers.

The code is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(int array[], int len) {
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("%d", array[i]);

    for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        printf(", ");
    }
} 
}

void print_min(int array[], int len, int min) {
for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
    if(array[i]<min) {
        min=array[i];
    }
}
}

void print_max(int array[], int len, int max) {
for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
    if (array[i]>max) {
        max=array[i];
    }
}
}

void sum(int array[], int len, int* x) {
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    *x = *x + array[i];
}
}

 

int main() {
int array[] = {9, 4, 7, 8, 10, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2};
int len = 10;

int min = array[0];
int max = array[0];

int summe = 0;

printf("Array: ");
print_array(array, len);
printf("\n");

print_min(array, len, min);
print_max(array, len, max);


printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);

sum(array, len, &summe);
printf("Summe: %d\n", summe);

return 0;
}
```

It would be really helpfull if somneone can say me where is my mistake to solve it.

I read the answers and after that change my code, but it doesnt work.
My new code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(int array[], int len) {
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("%d", array[i]);

    for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        printf(", ");
    }
} 
}


int min (int array[], int len) {
for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
    if(array[i]<z) {
        z=array[i];
    }
}
return z;
}


int max(int array[], int len) {
for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
    if (array[i]>y) {
        y=array[i];
    }
}
return y;
}

void sum(int array[], int len, int* x) {
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    *x = *x + array[i];
}
}



int main() {
int array[] = {9, 4, 7, 8, 10, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2};
int len = 10;

int z=array[0];
int y=array[0];


int Minimum = 0;
int Maximum = 0;

int summe = 0;

printf("Array: ");
print_array(array, len);
printf("\n");

Minimum = min(array, len);
Maximum = max(array, len);


printf("Minimum: %d\n", Minimum);
printf("Maximum: %d\n", Maximum);

sum(array, len, &summe);
printf("Summe: %d\n", summe);

return 0;
}
```

I receive error: "try.c:15:10: error: expected identifier or '('
int min (int array[], int len) {"

Comment: You need to pass `min` and `max` as reference or return min/max value from function and then use it.

Comment: `max` and `min` are passed by value, and the change in them is not visible outside the functions. Also `print_min/max` is a misnomer as these are not printing anything.

Comment: You seem to like void functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return` the result.

```
int sum(int array[], int len) {
    int x;

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        x += array[i];
    }

    return x;
}
```

You can print the result thusly:

```
printf("The sum of the array is %d.\n", sum(myArray, myArraySize));
```

You can, of course, pass the parameters by pointer if you wish, but that's not the canonical way to do it for simple functions like these.

A typical min function:

```
#include <limits.h>

int min(int array[], int len) {
    int x = INT_MAX;

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (array[i] < x)
           x = array[i];
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. User is asking about min and Max, but not the sum. But in principle, I agree user could have returned the values.

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't see any path forward unless the OP fixes the way he's writing his functions first.

Comment: @Abhishek: Anyway, I added a typical `min` function implementation.

Comment: Sure, that works too :-) But personally,  I think, using array[0] is better way of getting min/max. As array can have `INT_MAX` as value.

Comment: But personally, I think that using a void function when the actual value returnred is a scalar, is a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edit my question with a new code, it would be very nice if you can help me to see where my mistake is.

Comment: The min code you posted is not the same as the min code I posted.  Look at the code I posted, and try to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `min` and `max` as reference,

```
//Calling
print_min(array, len, &min);
print_max(array, len, &max);


//Function definition changes as follows,
void print_min(int array[], int len, int * min) {...}
void print_max(int array[], int len, int * max) {...}
```

Basically, `min` and `max` are passed by value, and that means scope ends when the function call is done. You need to pass them by reference. The same way you are passing `summe` variable.

Another *option* would be return min/max value from function and assign it to the variable.

p.s. naming of functions aren't great, as they are not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning or printing anything from `print_min` and `print_max` functions, so when you `printf` them they still have the value of array[0]. You should pass min and max by reference instead of passing them by value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are expecting print_min and print_max to alter the method parameters.

When a method is called, the actual values are pushed to the stack and new variables allocated for use in the method.

That is, when you call print_min(array, len, min) the value of min doesnt change in that scope. A new variable with the same value of min (and as a pure coincidence based on the method signature, named the same thing) is allocated for inside the print_min method.

You will want to add a return variable to print_min and print_max to be able to use them in the